# Counters are not updated in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have an issue with updating new counters in a cf. If I execute the next cql statements (the specific key is new):

```
UPDATE markerstats SET numbermarkers = numbermarkers + 1 WHERE projectid = 4 AND type = 'SNP';
```

The query execute without errors. And then I execute the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM markerstats
```

I do not get the row for the new updated counter. I have tried using the datastax java driver, devcenter and also directly throught. The definition of the cf is:

```
CREATE TABLE markerstats (
  projectid bigint,
  type text,
  numbermarkers counter,
  numberpartitions counter,
  PRIMARY KEY ((projectid), type)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

And I am using for testing purposes a cassandra (2.0.7) single node instance.

Anyone have an idea of what could be the problem?

NOTE: I have executed previously in the cf a DELETE statement

Comment: `I have executed previously in the cf a DELETE statement` What do you mean? Whether you have deleted a row for the key `projectid = 4 AND type = 'SNP'` and again are you trying to insert for the same key `projectid = 4 AND type = 'SNP'`?

Comment: Removal of counters is provided for definitive removal only. (https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters)

Comment: @JayaAnanthram Exactly I am talking about a update just right after a removal

Comment: @ThomasArnaud Ok, I understand that. But there should be way to insert again the same row or it is impossible to insert again a row counter when it has been previously deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the comments in the questions I could manage to restore the counters which were deleted by: updating the gc_grace_seconds of the cf to 0 and running a major compaction on the table.

Source: http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/14a9988tww/deleting-counters

Looks like the limitation on reuse counters after deleting them is going to be removed in some 3.* version (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9810)

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this situation in ScyllaDB (latest version 4.4.0) which is quite similar to Cassandra and support CQL. If you deleted the row previously, a new UPDATE command with the same WHERE condition won't insert the row to the DB. It seems like a bug but it is better not removing the counters. Instead, you can update all counter values to 0 rather than deletion.